# How to sync a folder in kubernetes statefulset

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-statefulset, sidecar

We are trying to create a solution where we want to replicate changes made to a folder inside any of the pods of the Statefulset. Any file changes inside that folder on any POD should also reflect in other pods. Is there a sidecar solution for this requirement? Because we know that Statefulset will create separate PVs for each POD and there won't be any common mount across the pods of the Statefulset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the NFS or file system like EFS using that you will be able to implement the ReadWritemany.

For ref **Azure File**.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: statefulset-azurefile
  labels:
    k8s-app: nginx
    version: v1
spec:
  serviceName: statefulset-azurefile
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: nginx
        version: v1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: statefulset-azurefile
        image: nginx
        volumeMounts:
        - name: persistent-storage
          mountPath: /mnt/azurefile
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: persistent-storage
      annotations:
        volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-class: azurefile
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteMany" ]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 5Gi
```

Demo : https://github.com/andyzhangx/demo/tree/master/linux/statefulset

If `volumeClaimTemplates` not work as expected use the `persistentVolumeClaim`

Article to read about **ReadWriteMany** access Mode :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-files-volume

If you are on other cloud providers like GCP, AWS, Oracle(OCI) provides different file services.

- GCP- **Filestore**
- AWS- **EFS**
- OCI- **Filestorage**

**OCI** article if you want to explore : https://enabling-cloud.github.io/oci-learning/manual/StaticPersistentVolumeOnOCI.html

Comment: Looks like a workable solution Harsh. Thanks for the suggestion. We will try to implement it now.

Comment: Sure, if that works you can also try out the MinIO or GlusterFS if don't wan to use the managed service for filesystem and implement `RWX`.